# Python Create a list of sublists from a list

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have the following list

```
colors = {a, b, c}
n = 3
```

Where both colors and n are built dynamically. I want to create a sublist using `n` and the elements of the list to get the following:

```
lcolors = [[a, a, a], [b, b, b], [c, c, c]]
```

if `colors` wasn't dynamic, it was easy:

```
lcolors =  [[a]*n, [b]*n, [c]*n]
```

I tried:

```
lcolors = colors * n
```

but that gave me a single list with 9 items instead of 3 sub-lists with 3 items each:

```
lcolors = [a, b, c, a, b, c, a, b, c]
```

None of the solutions offered here solve this:

- [Creating Sublists from a "List"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542593/creating-sublists-from-a-list)
- [Creating sequential sublists from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19624665/creating-sequential-sublists-from-a-list)
- [Create list of sublists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30157770/create-list-of-sublists)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you can use list comprehension:

```py
lcolors = [[color] * n for color in colors]
```

Answer (score 3):

You were really close. You just need a comprehension looping over `colors`

```
lcolors = [[x]*n for x in colors]
```